# How to Find top 10 expensive sql -Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have tried with below SQL query.

```
SELECT
    sql_id,
    child_number,
    sql_fulltext,
    elapsed_time,
    executions,
    round(elapsed_time_avg) elapsed_time_avg
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            command_type,
            sql_id,
            child_number,
            sql_fulltext,
            elapsed_time,
            cpu_time,
            disk_reads,
            executions,
            ( elapsed_time / executions ) elapsed_time_avg
        FROM
            v$sql
        WHERE
            executions > 0
        order by  elapsed_time_avg  desc 
    )
    where rownum <=10;
```

I expect all the time top 10 expensive query from the database. my query fetched but after some time change the SQL_id (results change) with a same SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct.  (Wowever, I suggest sorting by `ELAPSED_TIME` instead of an average, since it's the total run time that matters most.  A million fast queries can be worst than one slow query.)  But you just have to keep in mind that queries will disappear from `V$SQL` as they age out of the shared pool.  And it's hard to predict exactly how long something will stay in the shared pool.

You might want to look at the active session history, in `V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY`, which usually stores many hours worth of data.  And then look at `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY`, which stores 8 days of data by default.  You'll have to adjust your queries, since those two views don't store sums, they store a row for each wait.  You'll need to count the number of rows per SQL_ID to find the estimated wait time.  (`V$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY` samples once per second, `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY` samples once every 10 seconds.)

One of the most important thing to realize about tuning SQL is that you're not looking for perfection.  You don't want to trace every single statement, or you'll go crazy.  If you sample the system every X seconds, and a statement doesn't show up, then you almost certainly don't care about that statement.  It's fine if slow statements disappear from the top N list.